# Token-based interactive system meaning

Tags: terminology, hci

Recently I enrolled to HCI course, and there was mentioned that **WIMP** (*windows, icons, menus, pointer*) is a token-based interactive system. Does anyone knows what does token-based mean in WIMP system, since "token-based" was implied, because nonWIMP is (I guess) seen as non-token-based.

Comment: I have no idea what "token-based" should mean in this context. Can you provide a source?

Answer (score 1):

Well, WIMP is a very old term, I'm a bit surprised it's still in use.

Anyways, you could say most digital systems using graphical interfaces are WIMP. As a matter of fact, the term used to replace WIMP is [**GUI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).

With that being said, a token-based interactive system is a system that reacts to an user token (interaction). See an [**UML**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagram below:

[image]

In this model, the system reacts in 2 ways: *token-based* or *location aware*.

As the name implies, *location aware* means the system reacts to user's location in an automatic way (for example, maps or apps that read your location).

In opposition to the above, token-based requires some specific interaction which results in a token sent to the system, hence the name.

If you need more information, you can read this research paper with examples (from which I extracted the UML model): [**Formal notation for modeling location-aware and token-based interactive systems**](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Formal-notation-for-modeling-location-aware-and-token-based-interactive-systems-a-rep_fig1_221786477)