# Non-WIMP vs ubiquitous computing

Tags: hci

So, what would you call as a main difference between non-WIMP and
ubiquitous computing? I know that non-WIMP is seen as interface seen
after WIMP, kinda as a revolution of user interface, and that main
idea of ubiquitous computing is to get to something Mark Weiser called
"calm technology". Can we say that non-WIMP end goal is to get to be
called ubiquitous?

Answer (score 2):

Well, *non-WIMP* really has no particular meaning. If you call non-WIMP anything that is different to WIMP, then the scenario is incredibly broad. As I told you in [another answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120652/token-based-interactive-system-meaning), WIMP is a very old term and it fell into disuse decades ago. Maybe that's where the confusion lies, because WIMP is what now we call GUI (thus, non-GUI could be a text interface, a non digital interface or whatever).

Going into **ubiquitous computing** or *ubicom*, it has absolutely nothing to do with GUI, WIMP or any kind of particular interface representation. Instead, it's a model or concept.

Of course, on user's end, *ubicom* uses GUI most of the times, but it doesn't mean that it's necessary, or that this user (or **actor**, if you want to use UML models) is the only user.

An easy example: let's say you have an *ubicom* app that uses Google maps (an *ubicom* app by itself). The system will show you a GUI (or WIMP as you call it). But the backend might be used by a Sys-Admin using a console. One of them will use a GUI, one of them will use a [**TUI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) (Text-based user interface), the ubiquitous computing model is the same for both users

As for the *calm technology* part, it's correct that it's related to ubicom. However, **while *calm technology* needs *ubicom*, *ubicom* does't necessarily require *calm technology***

Comment: interesting answer! Do you know any good sources on this conversation (books, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "non-WIMP" as term for user interfaces is best explained by analogy. Nobody talks about "non-elephant animals". That is simply a class which is philosophically well defined, but lacks biological meaning. Similarly, it's reasonably simple to say whether a particular User Interface is WIMP or non-WIMP, but it's not very helpful.

Hence, all your attempts to ascribe attributes to "non-WIMP" fail as the category is far too broad.